# Testing which expression is greater

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities, expression-test

I have two expressions:

```
expr1 = e^2/(8 + 4*e + e^2)
```

and

```
expr2 = (d^2 - 2*d*e + e^2)/(8 + d^2 - 2*d*2 - 2*d*e + 4*e + e^2)
```

and one inequality:

```
0 < d < e < 1
```

I need to decide which expression is greater, and if one is not always greater, under what circumstances they change order. Equally, is it a decidable question?

Comment: Try `CylindricalDecomposition[0 < d < e < 1 && e^2/(8 + 4*e + e^2) < (d^2 - 2*d*e + e^2)/(8 + d^2 - 2*d*2 - 2*d*e + 4*e + e^2), {d, e}]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use

```
Assuming[0 < d < e < 1, FullSimplify[expr1 > expr2]]
(* True *)
```